# VHDL: convert Loop variable to string and pass to GENERIC

Tags: string, loops, generics, vhdl

I am looking for a way to initialize a ram-array which is generated in a FOR-GENERATE loop.
There is one .mif file for each ram which should be passed as an INIT_FILE Parameter (Intel/Altera).
Basicly I am thinking to convert the loop-index to a character, use that to concatenate to a specific file-name which then gets used in the GENERIC MAP.
An actual code-snipped is attached. That gives the following warning in modelsim: `Actual for generic "INIT_FILE" depends on value of signal "dat_string(p)"` and the string is empty. OK, that does not work. Why and can this be done in another way?

```
<snip>
ENTITY ch IS
<snip>
END ENTITY;
ARCHITECTURE rtl OF ch IS
    CONSTANT FILE_BASE : STRING := "dat_";
    CONSTANT FILE_END : STRING := ".mif";
    TYPE dat_str is array (0 to NRAM-1) of STRING(1 to 10);
    SIGNAL dat_string : dat_str;
BEGIN
gen : FOR p IN 0 TO NRAM - 1 GENERATE --
BEGIN
    dat_string(p) <= FILE_BASE & integer'image(p) & FILE_END;
    i_wlut : ENTITY work.lut
        GENERIC MAP(
            INIT_FILE => dat_string(p)
        )
        PORT MAP
        (
        <snip>
        );
END GENERATE gen;
END ARCHITECTURE rtl;
```

Comment: What purpose does the array serve? Instead of `INIT_FILE => FILE_BASE & integer'image(p) & FILE_END;`

Comment: Provide a [mcve] instead of a snippet demonstrating the undisclosed problem - `FILE_BASE & integer'image(p) & FILE_END;` will produce a string length 9 when p < 10 or longer than 10 when p > 99 while an element of an object of type `dat_str` is declared to have a length of 10. Brian's comment suggestion requires generic INIT_FILE be declared without a subtype indication constraint in entity `lut` (show that too, instantiation in `ch` uses reserved word `ENTITY` requiring `lut` be present in library `work` during analysis of `ch`).

Comment: "*... and the string is empty*." The value of a signal can be used here but it's not useful. Without an initial value each subelement of dat_string(p) would be the left most value of type CHARACTER (a NUL), causing the empty appearing string (NUL isn't a graphic character). While not listed in the Enforcing Strict 1076 Compliance section of the Modelsim user manual using the vcom flag `-pendaticerrors` should produce an error for the length mismatch when simulating. Modelsim takes liberties with the standard to support the same code generator for multiple HDLs.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the string as a constant. Generates are unrolled at elaboration time when signals only have their initial value, which in this case would make `dat_string` all `NUL`.

Simply remove the `dat_string` signal entirely, and simply assign the generic to the string you created:

```
INIT_FILE => FILE_BASE & integer'image(p) & FILE_END
```